# Why does a number appear just before [\r][\n] in a SOAP response

Tags: http, soap, http-headers, wso2, wso2-esb

When wire log is enabled in WSO2ESB I noticed following response from ESB to client. And just before the body and after the headers I noticed that there's a line starting with number 339

> "339[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

Could someone please explain what is this number and why its there? Following is the full wire log.

```
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2016 06:48:55 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "339[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-06-09 07:48:55,715] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body>....
```

Comment: I guess, it should be Content-Length.

Answer (score 1):

By default wso2 ESB is sending data to downstreams in chunked format. when using chunked format server will mention the length of each chunk before sending the chunk of the data in hexadecimal format like 339[\r\n']

I also had same problem and was able to resolve by adding below property below send mediator

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, they are looking for an explanation of what they see. There does not seem to be an actual problem.

Comment: modified the answer.